# Separate substring by comma SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have string from which I have to extract substring and query on their values.

```
declare @str varchar(max)
@str='Hello,world,continent,nation,city'

select * from mytable
where col_word in(SELECT REPLACE(@str,',',''','''))
```

The sub query

```
SELECT REPLACE(@str,',',''',''')
```

results in

```
Hello,'world','continent','nation','city
```

I want the above result be enclosed by single quotes so that it can work for `IN`

But this returns only for first col_word value `Hello` which is first substring in `@str`.

What should I do ?

Comment: You can't use `IN` like that

Comment: I want the above result be enclosed by single quotes so that it can work for IN

Comment: `IN` does not take a comma seperated string

Comment: There is a world of difference betweeen `IN ('a','b','c')` and `IN (@myString)`.  No matter what `@mystring` looks like, it is still ***one*** string and *not* a ***list*** of items.  Search SO and the internet for SplitString functions, and then try this... `IN (SELECT * FROM fn_split(@myString))`.  *[There are many split string functions on the web, they take a string, and return a table where each row is one item from your list.  Then, having multiple items, your IN condition will work.]*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

You cannot make part of your query as string. We have to make the whole query as a string, then execute it with [**EXEC()**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188332.aspx) command.. or [**sp_executesql**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188001.aspx) stored procedure. The latter is recommended.

```
declare @str varchar(max);
select @str='Hello,world,continent,nation,city';

SELECT @str=''''+REPLACE(@str,',',''',''')+''''
exec('select * from mytable where col_word in('+@str +')')
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
declare @str varchar(max)
declare @pattern varchar(max)
SET @str='Hello,world,continent,nation,city'
SELECT REPLACE(@str,',',''',''')
SET @pattern = REPLACE('Hello,world,continent,nation,city', ',', ''',''')
EXEC('select * from mytable where col_word in(''' + @pattern + ''')')
```