# LIKE condition with comma separated values

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-like, sql-in

This may seem silly but I am working on an old system where we don't have separate table for project. We have a table something like this.

```
|        PROJECTNAME | EMPID |
|--------------------|-------|
|     casio calc new |     1 |
|           calc new |     2 |
|               tech |     3 |
| financial calc new |     4 |
|              casio |     5 |
```

Now what we want is to select EmpID from the above table where ProjectName can be either casio or calc. And we have user inputs for multiple selection like `casio, calc`. Meaning if user inputs `casio, calc` it should find `ProjectName LIKE '%casio%' OR '%calc%'`.

I really don't have any idea how can this be possible.

```
SELECT * FROM ProjectDetails
WHERE ProjectName LIKE 'casio, calc';
```

I searched for [SQL LIKE with IN](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=SQL%20LIKE%20with%20IN) but I couldn't find any solution. Do anyone have idea how can I achieve this? Or any other approach to use? I am trying this on [this fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/33e57b/2).

Comment: possible duplicate of [Using SQL LIKE and IN together](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2318126/using-sql-like-and-in-together)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go. You can create a dynamic query with the help of `REPLACE` function with a little bit *hack*. Then use `EXEC` function to execute that query.

```
DECLARE @str VARCHAR(MAX)
SELECT @str='casio,calc'

SELECT @str='LIKE ''%'+REPLACE(@str,',','%'' OR ProjectName LIKE ''%')+'%'''

EXEC('SELECT * FROM ProjectDetails WHERE
     ProjectName ' + @str +'');
```

Output:

```
|        PROJECTNAME | EMPID |
|--------------------|-------|
|     casio calc new |     1 |
|           calc new |     2 |
| financial calc new |     4 |
|              casio |     5 |
```

#### [SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/33e57b/44)

Thanks to [Joe G Joseph](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13529347/1369235) for his hint.

Answer (score 1):

The solution is to use several `LIKE` conditions:

```
SELECT *
FROM ProjectDetails
WHERE ProjectName LIKE '%casio%'
OR ProjectName LIKE '%calc%';
```

Comment: I would add just a hint, Always put or conditions inside parenteshis :)

Comment: Hello, Isn't there any dynamic solution?

Comment: @user3829465: SQL isn't a dynamic language, so your question doesn't make sense. Aren't you building the query in a real programming language? If not, then you need to find out how you can build queries at runtime in your database. I don't know SQL Server to help you there.

Comment: Or parse the delimited list of values.

Answer (score 1):

Like doesn't except comma delimited values.  You are going to have to dynamically add an or condition for each passed in value.

It has to be of the form:

```
ProjectName Like'%param1%' OR ProjectName Like '%param2%'
```

Answer (score 0):

We declare @str variable and store value we want to search and using REPLACE function place like keyword for every value and assign it to main query and execute it, you can get result

```
DECLARE @Query VARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @str VARCHAR(MAX)
SELECT @str='tech,casio, calc,casio calc new'
SELECT @str='LIKE ''%'+REPLACE(@str,',','%'' OR ProjectName LIKE ''%')+'%'''
set @Query ='SELECT * FROM ProjectDetails WHERE
     ProjectName  ' + @str
exec( @Query)
```